# Android geocoding. Getting an exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I want to get full address with geocoding and I am providing a particular position in the form of `LatLng`. But when I am running the code I am getting exception in log.

**Panic.java**

public class Panic extends Activity {

```
String address;
TextView result;
LatLng position;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.panic);

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    ActionBar action_bar = getActionBar();
    action_bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    position = new LatLng(17.6913913,75.9234617);

    Toast.makeText(this, position.latitude + "," + position.longitude, 1).show();

    String FullAddress = getFullAddress();

    result.setText(FullAddress);

}

private String getFullAddress() {

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);

    List<Address> list = null;
    try {
        list = gc.getFromLocation(position.latitude, position.longitude, 10);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String add_1 = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String add_2 = list.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    String add_3 = list.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

    return add_1 + ", " + add_2 + ", " + add_3 + ".";
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        flag=1;
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beproject.ourway/com.beproject.ourway.Panic}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at com.beproject.ourway.Panic.onCreate(Panic.java:45)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
04-04 09:18:42.120: E/AndroidRuntime(30593):    ... 11 more
04-04 09:18:42.131: I/System.out(30593): [socket][2:53181] exception
04-04 09:18:42.131: I/System.out(30593): [CDS]close[53181]
04-04 09:18:42.132: I/System.out(30593): [socket][2] connection clients4.google.com/216.58.220.14:443;LocalPort=45123(0)
04-04 09:18:42.133: I/System.out(30593): [CDS]connect[clients4.google.com/216.58.220.14:443] tm:90
04-04 09:18:42.134: D/Posix(30593): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.beproject.ourway :443 
04-04 09:18:42.218: I/System.out(30593): [socket][/192.168.1.4:45123] connected
04-04 09:18:42.218: I/System.out(30593): [CDS]rx timeout:0
```

Comment: What is line num `45` in `Panic.java` ?

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, position.latitude + "," + position.longitude, 1).show();

Comment: @ Gaurav Deshpande if commenting this line working fine?

Comment: check if getFullAddress() returns null.

Answer (score 0):

check here    if getFullAddress returns Null

`String FullAddress = getFullAddress();`

if it returns Null you may get NullPointerException